# How to handle multiple source-files debugging with idle3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I know how to debug a single file, but a breakpoint on an imported file does not work so far.

**test1.py**

```
import test2

print(do_stuff)
```

**test2.py**

```
def do_stuff():
   str = "hello world" # <- set breakpoint here
   return str
```

When setting a breakpoint in test2.py and running test1.py in idle3, the program does not stop. How to handle multiple source-files debugging?

Comment: do you have to work with idle? there are so many better and free alternatives out there where debugging is much easier

Comment: which one would you recommend most?

Comment: PyCharm is my favorite. It is very rich in features (including auto-complete etc.), and the community edition is completely free.

Comment: @noamgot If John had asked for opinions on what editor or other software to use, the question would have been closed as 'off topic'. So is offering such opinions.  In this case, IDLE works as expected when given correct code.  In the posted code, it did not stop on the breakpoint line within the function because execution never reached that line, because the function was never called.  I expect that this would be true for any debugger and any language.  It happens that omitting ()s from a function call is a common Python beginner mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is buggy in that it never runs the line with a breakpoint, which is within a function that is not called.  I just tested in 3.5.4 and 3.7.0b1 on Windows and breakpoints in an imported file work fine.

```
# a/tem.py (in path)
a = 3
b = 4  # breakpoint
def c():
    d = 5  # breakpoint
    return 'c ran'

# a/tem2.py
from a.tem import c
print(c)
print(c())

# prints
<function c at 0x0000023921979840>
c ran
```

Running buggy code in a different IDE will not make it magically run.